# How to refresh token with Google API client?

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, access-token, google-analytics-api

I've been playing around with the Google Analytics API (V3) and have run into som errors. Firstly, everything is set up correct and worked with my testing account. But when I want to grab data from another profile ID (Same Google Accont/GA Account) I get an 403 Error. The strange thing is that data from some GA accounts will return data whilst other generate this error.

I've revoked the token and authenticated one more time, and now it seems like I can grab data from all of my accounts. Problem solved? Not. As the access key will expire, I will run into the same issue again.

If I have understood things right, one could use the resfreshToken to get a new authenticationTooken.

The problem is, when I run:

```
$client->refreshToken(refresh_token_key)
```

the following error is returned:

```
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'
```

I’ve checked the code behind the refreshToken method and tracked the request back to the “apiOAuth2.php” file. All parameters are sent correctly. The grant_type is hard coded to ‘refresh_token’ within the method, so it’s hard for me to understand what’s wrong. The parameter array looks like this:

```
Array ( [client_id] => *******-uqgau8uo1l96bd09eurdub26c9ftr2io.apps.googleusercontent.com [client_secret] => ******** [refresh_token] => 1\/lov250YQTMCC9LRQbE6yMv-FiX_Offo79UXimV8kvwY [grant_type] => refresh_token )
```

The procedure is as follows.

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setClientId($config['oauth2_client_id']);
$client->setClientSecret($config['oauth2_client_secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($config['oauth2_redirect_uri']);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');
$client->setState('offline');

$client->setAccessToken($config['token']); // The access JSON object.

$client->refreshToken($config['refreshToken']); // Will return error here
```

Is this a bug, or have I completely misunderstood something?

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug or something but i'm currently refreshing the access token using a raw CURL http request and it's working fine.

Comment: Seorch... you figure this one out yet? Same issue here.

Comment: @gremo could you share the raw CURL http request you used here? Would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 80):

So i finally figured out how to do this. The basic idea is that you have the token you get the first time you ask for authentication. This first token has a refresh token. The first original token expires after an hour. After an hour you have to use the refresh token from the first token to get a new usable token. You use `$client->refreshToken($refreshToken)` to retrieve a new token. I will call this "temp token." You need to store this temp token as well because after an hour it expires as well and note it does not have a refresh token associated with it. In order to get a new temp token you need to use the method you used before and use the first token's refreshtoken. I have attached code below, which is ugly, but im new at this...

```
//pull token from database
$tokenquery="SELECT * FROM token WHERE type='original'";
$tokenresult = mysqli_query($cxn,$tokenquery);
if($tokenresult!=0)
{
    $tokenrow=mysqli_fetch_array($tokenresult);
    extract($tokenrow);
}
$time_created = json_decode($token)->created;
$t=time();
$timediff=$t-$time_created;
echo $timediff."<br>";
$refreshToken= json_decode($token)->refresh_token;


//start google client note:
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('');
$client->setScopes(array());
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
$client->setRedirectUri('');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setDeveloperKey('');

//resets token if expired
if(($timediff>3600)&&($token!=''))
{
    echo $refreshToken."</br>";
    $refreshquery="SELECT * FROM token WHERE type='refresh'";
    $refreshresult = mysqli_query($cxn,$refreshquery);
    //if a refresh token is in there...
    if($refreshresult!=0)
    {
        $refreshrow=mysqli_fetch_array($refreshresult);
        extract($refreshrow);
        $refresh_created = json_decode($token)->created;
        $refreshtimediff=$t-$refresh_created;
        echo "Refresh Time Diff: ".$refreshtimediff."</br>";
        //if refresh token is expired
        if($refreshtimediff>3600)
        {
            $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
        $newtoken=$client->getAccessToken();
        echo $newtoken."</br>";
        $tokenupdate="UPDATE token SET token='$newtoken' WHERE type='refresh'";
        mysqli_query($cxn,$tokenupdate);
        $token=$newtoken;
        echo "refreshed again";
        }
        //if the refresh token hasn't expired, set token as the refresh token
        else
        {
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
           echo "use refreshed token but not time yet";
        }
    }
    //if a refresh token isn't in there...
    else
    {
        $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
        $newtoken=$client->getAccessToken();
        echo $newtoken."</br>";
        $tokenupdate="INSERT INTO token (type,token) VALUES ('refresh','$newtoken')";
        mysqli_query($cxn,$tokenupdate);
        $token=$newtoken;
        echo "refreshed for first time";
    }      
}

//if token is still good.
if(($timediff<3600)&&($token!=''))
{
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

$service = new Google_DfareportingService($client);
```

Comment: Instead of checking for 3600 seconds, you should use $client->isAccessTokenExpired()

Comment: Small update. In the latest version, when you request a refresh token the new access token that is returned now comes with a new refresh token.  So essentially, you can use the updated json token to replace the previous json token, and do not need to retain the initial access token any longer. .

Comment: Note that `$client->isAccessTokenExpired()` will still only check the times held locally to see if it thinks the token has expired. The token may still have expired and the local application will only really know when it tries to use it. In this case the API client will return an exception, and will *not* automatically refresh the token.

Comment: @Jason Not true now I think. I see the  below return statement in the "isAccessTokenExpired" method : return ($created + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();

Answer (score 48):

The problem is in the refresh token:

```
[refresh_token] => 1\/lov250YQTMCC9LRQbE6yMv-FiX_Offo79UXimV8kvwY
```

When a string with a `'/'` gets `json encoded`, It is escaped with a `'\'`, hence you need to remove it.

The refresh token in your case should be:

```
1/lov250YQTMCC9LRQbE6yMv-FiX_Offo79UXimV8kvwY
```

What i'm assuming you've done is that you've printed the json string which google sent back and copied and pasted the token into your code because if you `json_decode` it then it will correctly remove the `'\'` for you!

Comment: amazing mention, made my day! saved hours!

Comment: You saved my day !

Comment: I wish i could upvote this 100 times. I was about to make a hole into a wall with my keyboard after staring at "bad grant" message for several hours after trying absolutely everything to make the token work. Fricking google man, why use slashes, just why?

Answer (score 21):

here is the snippet to set token, before that make sure the access type should be set to **offline**

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

To refresh token

```
$google_token= json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']);
$client->refreshToken($google_token->refresh_token);
```

this will refresh your token, you have to update it in session for that you can do

```
 $_SESSION['access_token']= $client->getAccessToken()
```

Comment: you made my day with this :) thank you very much, a lot more simple than i thought it would be as i have been spending a lot of time getting nowhere :D

Answer (score 16):

The access type should be set to `offline`. `state` is a variable you set for your own use, not the API's use.

Make sure you have the [latest version of the client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list) and add:

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

See [Forming the URL](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#formingtheurl) for an explanation of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks jk. I've downloaded the latest version and revoked access to the app for my account. Then I granted access one more time and stored the accessToken and refreshToken. The thing is, I've always been given a refreshToken, even if the setAccessType have been omitted. Anyhow, when I run $client->refreshToken(refresh-token-key), I still get the "invalid_grant" error. I've checked the auth-url and it defaults to "force". If I change it to "auto" and runs the authenticate method, I'm not redirected as I already granted access. But the respons is an accessToken without a refresh one. Any ideas?

Comment: @seorch.me Sounds crazy but is it possible that you have to set up a new `$client` (`$client = new apiClient();`) to use the refresh token?

Comment: @seorch.me you must set `$client->setApprovalPrompt('force')` as well as `$client->setAccessType('offline')` to get a new refresh token during authorisation. Without forcing the user to approve the scope of access, Google assumes you are going to keep using the old refresh token.

Answer (score 14):

*The answer posted by @uri-weg worked for me but as I did not find his explanations very clear, let me reword it a little.*

During the first access permission sequence, in the callback, when you get to the point where you receive an authentication code, you must **save the access token and the refresh token** as well.

The reason is google api sends you an access token with a refresh token only when prompting for access permission. The next access tokens will be sent without any refresh token (unless you use the `approval_prompt=force` option).

**The refresh token you received the first time stays valid until the user revokes access permission.**

In simplistic php, an example of the callback sequence would be:

```
// init client
// ...

$authCode = $_GET['code'];
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
// $accessToken needs to be serialized as json
$this->saveAccessToken(json_encode($accessToken));
$this->saveRefreshToken($accessToken['refresh_token']);
```

And later on, in simplistic php, the connection sequence would be:

```
// init client
// ...

$accessToken = $this->loadAccessToken();
// setAccessToken() expects json
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // reuse the same refresh token
    $client->refreshToken($this->loadRefreshToken());
    // save the new access token (which comes without any refresh token)
    $this->saveAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
}
```

Comment: perfect, worked a lot. only thing I would say is that you should explain you need to pass the json object not just the token as a string.

Comment: @OliverBayes-Shelton Hi. Thanks. I thought `// setAccessToken() expects json` was sufficient. Or is it for another part of the code ?

Comment: This works great for me, but do you know if this code handles situations where a token expires due to exceeding the limit of 50 token refreshes? Details about 'Token Expiration' can be found here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

Comment: It seems that the latest 2.0 version is now returning the refresh token in the access token array.  This means that saving the access token also saves the refresh token, as the refresh token is included.  In response to the refresh token expiring, I'm guessing that would have to tested for and handled explicitly - remember the 50 limit is "per user per client", ie it's 50 per client so you're unlikely to hit it, especially if you use included scopes to combine tokens.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code which I am using in my project and it is working fine:

```
public function getClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPNAME);       // app name
    $client->setClientId(CLIENTID);             // client id
    $client->setClientSecret(CLIENTSECRET);     // client secret 
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);      // redirect uri
    $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');

    $client->setAccessType('offline');         // generates refresh token

    $token = $_COOKIE['ACCESSTOKEN'];          // fetch from cookie

    // if token is present in cookie
    if($token){
        // use the same token
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
    }

    // this line gets the new token if the cookie token was not present
    // otherwise, the same cookie token
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();

    if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){  // if token expired
        $refreshToken = json_decode($token)->refresh_token;

        // refresh the token
        $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    }

    return $client;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue; my script that worked yesterday, for some odd reason did not today. No changes.

Apparently this was because my system clock was off by 2.5 (!!) seconds, syncing with NTP fixed it.

See also: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Solving_invalid_grant_errors

Comment: That answer helped me a lot, man. You probably saved me a lot of time. A lot! Thanks!
I just executed `sudo apt-get install ntp` on my Debian machine to install NTP. It synchronized the clock and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes Refresh Token i not generated by using `$client->setAccessType ("offline");`.

Try this:

```
$client->setAccessType ("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");
```

Comment: To be more specific, it looks like the Refresh token is included in your *first* authorization.  If you save and then use it, I believe (according to others, not verified) that the refresh token continues to be returned.  The doco also now says that they will auto-refresh the access token if they have a refresh token, which means it's simply a matter of managing the refresh token securely.  setApprovalPrompt('force') does force a refresh token to be issued subsequently; without it you won't get another one.

Answer (score 4):

FYI: The 3.0 Google Analytics API will automatically refresh the access token if you have a refresh token when it expires so your script never needs `refreshToken`.

(See the `Sign` function in `auth/apiOAuth2.php`)

Comment: "Automatically refresh" means that I just have to ask for getAccessToken() and I will get a refreshed one back? But I have to set the refresh token out of the DB first, right? Otherwise the refresh would work without a refresh token and I don't think this would work

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the access token to file or database as a json string during the initial authorization request, and set the access type to offline `$client->setAccessType("offline")`

Then, during subsequent api requests, grab the access token from your file or db and pass it to the client:

```
$accessToken = json_decode($row['token'], true);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

Now you need to check if the token has expired:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // access token has expired, use the refresh token to obtain a new one
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    // save the new token to file or db
    // ...json_encode($client->getAccessToken())
```

The `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` function will do the work for you and provide a new access token, save it back to your file or database.

Answer (score 2):

I used the example by smartcodes with the current version of the Google API, but that one didn't work. I think his API is too outdated.

So, I just wrote my own version, based on one of the API examples... It outputs access token, request token, token type, ID token, expiration time and creation time as strings

If your client credentials and developer key are correct, this code should work out of the box.

```
<?php
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Get Token");
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and to register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    return;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    $client->revokeToken();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <header><h1>Get Token</h1></header>
        <?php
        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $token = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
            echo "Access Token = " . $token->access_token . '<br/>';
            echo "Refresh Token = " . $token->refresh_token . '<br/>';
            echo "Token type = " . $token->token_type . '<br/>';
            echo "Expires in = " . $token->expires_in . '<br/>';
            echo "ID Token = " . $token->id_token . '<br/>';
            echo "Created = " . $token->created . '<br/>';
            echo "<a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
        } else {
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, could you explain me why this line: `$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`. Why you redirect to same page? is this necessary?

Comment: @Tropicalista : It isn't necessary to reload the page per se, but this is the way authentication flows are typically implemented.

Comment: but you are not using the refresh token to get a new access token if access token is expired.

Answer (score 2):

Google has made some changes since this question was originally posted.

Here is my currently working example.

```
    public function update_token($token){

    try {

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAccessType("offline"); 
        $client->setAuthConfig(APPPATH . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'google' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'client_secrets.json');  
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true); 
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR); 
        $client->setAccessToken($token);

        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $refresh_token = $client->getRefreshToken();
            if(!empty($refresh_token)){
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);      
                $token = $client->getAccessToken();
                $token['refresh_token'] = json_decode($refresh_token);
                $token = json_encode($token);
            }
        }

        return $token;

    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        $error = json_decode($e->getMessage());
        if(isset($error->error->message)){
            log_message('error', $error->error->message);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem with *google/google-api-php-client v2.0.0-RC7*
and after search for 1 hours, i solved this problem using **json_encode**
like this:

```
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $newToken = json_decode(json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        $client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
        file_put_contents(storage_path('app/client_id.txt'), json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This here works very good, maybe it could help anybody:

index.php

```
session_start();

require_once __DIR__.'/client.php';

if(!isset($obj->error) && isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'] && isset($obj->expires_in)) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google API Token Test</title>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
search('Music Mix 2010');
function search(q) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'action.php?q='+q,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'refresh') location.reload();
            else $('#response').html(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data)));
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else header('Location: '.filter_var('https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'/oauth2callback.php', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
?>
```

oauth2callback.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('auth.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://'.filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);

if(isset($_GET['code']) && $_GET['code']) {
    $client->authenticate(filter_var($_GET['code'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $_SESSION['access_token']['refresh_token'];
    setcookie('refresh_token', $_SESSION['refresh_token'], time()+60*60*24*180, '/', filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL), true, true);
    header('Location: '.filter_var('https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    exit();
}
else header('Location: '.filter_var($client->createAuthUrl(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
exit();

?>
```

client.php

```
// https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('auth.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_FORCE_SSL);

// Delete Cookie Token
#setcookie('refresh_token', @$_SESSION['refresh_token'], time()-1, '/', filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL), true, true);

// Delete Session Token
#unset($_SESSION['refresh_token']);

if(isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
    $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['refresh_token']) && $_COOKIE['refresh_token']) {
    $client->refreshToken($_COOKIE['refresh_token']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token='.urlencode(@$_SESSION['access_token']['access_token']);
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Google API Token Test');
$json = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$obj = json_decode($json);

?>
```

action.php

```
session_start();

require_once __DIR__.'/client.php';

if(isset($obj->error)) {
    echo 'refresh';
    exit();
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'] && isset($obj->expires_in) && isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
    $response = $service->search->listSearch('snippet', array('q' => filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS), 'maxResults' => '1', 'type' => 'video'));
    echo json_encode($response['modelData']);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use google-api-php-client v2.2.2 I get a new token with `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken();` if function call without params, it returns an updated access token and the refreshed token is not lost.

```
if ($client->getAccessToken() && $client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $new_token=$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken();
    $token_data = $client->verifyIdToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code snippet to get your refresh token

```
    <?php

    require_once 'src/apiClient.php';
    require_once 'src/contrib/apiTasksService.php';

    $client = new apiClient();
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $tasksService = new apiTasksService($client);

    $auth = $client->authenticate();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    // the refresh token
    $refresh_token = $token['refresh_token'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Authentication on google: OAuth2 keeps returning 'invalid_grant'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025698/authentication-on-google-oauth2-keeps-returning-invalid-grant)

"You should reuse the access token you get after the first successful authentication. You will get an invalid_grant error if your previous token has not expired yet. Cache it somewhere so you can reuse it."

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got into this issue and I found this to be the simplest and cleanest way to get proper token.

```php
public function authenticate()
{
    $access_token = 'OLD_TOKEN';
    $refresh_token = 'OLD_TOKEN';

    if ($access_token) {
        $this->client->setAccessToken($access_token);
    }

    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
         $this->client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    }
}
```

I have `client` as property on the class that's why I am using `$this->client`.