# How to use refresh token to get authorized in background and getting access token?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, oauth, access-token

I am trying to get accessToken using refreshToken, below I have posted my code please someone guide me.

It is from a wordpress plugin I am developing, I only need to retrieve pageViews 
and pagePath so not preferring using a available plugin.

Taken reference from [Use OAuth Refresh Token to Obtain New Access Token - Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880928/use-oauth-refresh-token-to-obtain-new-access-token-google-api)

```
 if( isset( $this->options['authenication_code'] ) ){   //plugin setting page settings 
                global $wpdb;
                $resultset = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT `refreshToken` FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'analyticaAnalytics WHERE authenication_code ="' . $this->options["authenication_code"] . '"', ARRAY_A );
                var_dump( $resultset['refreshToken'] ); //retrieved refreshToken from database
                if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              //boolean true
                    $client->refreshToken( $resultset['refreshToken'] ); 
                    var_dump( $client );//getting blank
                }
            }
```

**../google-api-php-client/src/Google/Auth/oauth2.php**

```
private function refreshTokenRequest($params)
  { 
    if (isset($params['assertion'])) {

      $this->client->getLogger()->info(
          'OAuth2 access token refresh with Signed JWT assertion grants.'
      );
    } else {
        $this->client->getLogger()->info('OAuth2 access token refresh');
    }

    $http = new Google_Http_Request(
        self::OAUTH2_TOKEN_URI,
        'POST',
        array(),
        $params
    );

    $http->disableGzip();
    $request = $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($http);
    //var_dump( $request );exit;//response 400, invalid grant
    $code = $request->getResponseHttpCode();

    $body = $request->getResponseBody();
    if (200 == $code) {
      $token = json_decode($body, true);
      if ($token == null) {
        throw new Google_Auth_Exception("Could not json decode the access token");
      }

      if (! isset($token['access_token']) || ! isset($token['expires_in'])) {
        throw new Google_Auth_Exception("Invalid token format");
      }

      if (isset($token['id_token'])) {
        $this->token['id_token'] = $token['id_token'];
      }
      $this->token['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
      $this->token['expires_in'] = $token['expires_in'];
      $this->token['created'] = time();
    } else {
      throw new Google_Auth_Exception("Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '$body'", $code);
    }
  }
```

After spending a lot of time I got the error is responsecode 400 for `$request = $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($http);` and that is invalid grant.

[full code](https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/8d32f6eec2146a5c8ded)

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: @DaImTo no, I am not getting any error or output .

Comment: @DaImTo added the full code gistgithub link to my question .

Comment: All information relevant to solve the problem should be embedded in the question here on Stack Overflow. Also, you should really attempt to go further in explaining what's going wrong, what you expect, and what you see instead.

Comment: @Nick I have edited my question, with the error I found and the function where I got error and you can also notice, I have provided a link to gistgithub.

Comment: @Nick I solved this just now.

Comment: @DaImTo I solved it just now.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu you should post your solution as an answer to this question now

Comment: @Nick I did it once for one of my question , that was having 3 votes, some people come and down voted the question and as well as the answer that is why I had not posted the answer here :(

Comment: @Nick I am posting the answer , let people vote me down or up , some people will definitely need it.

Comment: @DaImTo I have just added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how , I solved the problem, We need to store the refreshToken in our database and using that refreshToken, We can get another accessToken .which can be used to get the result and it does not need another authentication .

```
<?php
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfigFile(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/client_secrets.json');
        $client->setRedirectUri( site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=analytica-admin-settings');
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        if ( isset( $_GET['code'] )) {

            if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){

                $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

                $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
                $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();

                $analytica_tokens = json_encode( array( 'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ),'accessToken' =>  $accessToken, 'refreshToken' => $refreshToken ) );
                update_option( 'analytica_tokens', $analytica_tokens );
            } 
        } else {
            $resultset = json_decode(get_option('analytica_tokens'));

            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                if( isset( $resultset ) ){
                    $refreshToken = $resultset->refreshToken;
                    $client->refreshToken( $refreshToken );
                    $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();           
                    $analytica_tokens = json_encode( array( 'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 'accessToken' =>  $accessToken, 'refreshToken' => $refreshToken ) );
                    update_option( 'analytica_tokens', $analytica_tokens );
                } else {
                    echo 'You need to reauthorize the application to get the analytics report.';
                }
            }
        }
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        ?>
         <a class="connect-to-google-analytics" href='<?php echo $auth_url; ?>'  id="loginText">Connect To Your Google Analytics Account </a>
        <?php
        if( isset($accessToken) ){
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken ? $accessToken : $refreshToken;
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            // Create an authorized analytics service object.
            $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

            // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
            $profile = $this->getFirstProfileId($analytics);

            // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
            $this->results = $this->getResults($analytics, $profile);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but doesn't saving the refresh token in a database make the use of refresh tokens irrelevant? You might as well use sessions at this point. Access and refresh tokens should be kept stateless to make sense.