# Error 403 refreshing GMAIL token with PHP

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to get emails from Gmail but I'm not able to refresh token. I also followed this question but I don't know why it doesn't work

[How to refresh token with Google API client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241213/how-to-refresh-token-with-google-api-client)

This is how I do it:

```
$email="xxxx@gmail.com"; //It can't be "me";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
$client->setRedirectUri($this->redirect_url);
$client->setState('offline');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setLoginHint($email);

$client->setAccessToken($gmail['access_token']);

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
{
    $access_token= json_decode($gmail['access_token'],true);
    $refresh=$client->refreshToken($access_token["refresh_token"]);
    $new_token_array_str=$client->getAccessToken();

    /*
    Old Token ($access_token):
    ------------------
    array (size=5)
      'access_token' => string 'ya29.xQE0___' (length=73)
      'token_type' => string 'Bearer' (length=6)
      'expires_in' => int 3600
      'refresh_token' => string '1/M57-GPcccc' (length=66)
      'created' => int 1438679813

    New token:
    ----------
    array (size=3)
      'access_token' => string 'ya29.xQEllll-jjj-jjj' (length=73)
      'expires_in' => int 3600
      'created' => int 1438689530
    */
}

$j=0;
do 
{
    try
    {
        $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($email, $opt_param);
        if ($messagesResponse->getMessages()) 
        {
            $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
            $pageToken = $messagesResponse->getNextPageToken();
        }
        $j++;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}while ($pageToken);
```

And this is what I get:

> An error occurred: Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/xxxx%40gmail.com%20/messages?q=in%3Ainbox:
>   (403) Delegation denied for xxxx@gmail.com

The first time, I get the emails. My problem is when token access token has expired, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);`?

Comment: I've just do it and I receive the same 403 error

Comment: Can you describe this line $refresh=$client->refreshToken($access_token["refresh_token"] like what are you passing to refresh? Sorry I didn't understand..

Comment: I passing the refresh_token that I get on my first call (Old Token ($access_token)). But it works, because the access_token changes.... But I don't know why I receive "Delegation denied"

Comment: @titolancreo Why cant use "me", if you are using Access Token of an authenticated user?

Comment: Because using "me" means that the user must be logged in with that email. And people sometimes use differents emails.

Comment: @titolancreo Using 'me' would mean that you are impersonating the user whose access_token is being sent with the request. Its the usual way of making API calls on Google Services.

Comment: Sorry for answer too late, but this worked! Thanks a lot