# How should I do with refresh token (Google calendar)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

[image]

In the past for days I wasted of my good much time
now I managed to get refresh token.. I couldn't get a refresh token before..

My purpose is to synchronize Google calendar data without Google login of users

What I did to do so:

1. I stored token information in my database
2. when user wants to synchronize I used the stored information to pull data from Google calendar API
   but then the token has expiration date, which is an hour
3. I assume I can get an usable token using refresh token and pull data from Google calendar api again ( but how ? )

extra question : can I get another refresh token from the previous refresh token? Is it like I can get a refresh token over and over again?

Here's some my code:

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR); // CALENDAR READONLY 는 읽기만 가능
    $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
    $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
    $client->setAccessType ("offline");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt ("force");
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/smart_mirror/GoogleCalendarApi-master/public/api/cal');
    $this->client = $client;
}


$refresh_token=$this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken()); 
$this->client->getAuth()->refreshToken($this->client->getAuth()->getRefreshToken()); 
$refresh_token=$this->client->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access
>   to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can
>   obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to
>   obtain new access tokens.
>
> Note: Save refresh tokens in secure long-term storage and continue to
>   use them as long as they remain valid. Limits apply to the number of
>   refresh tokens that are issued per client-user combination, and per
>   user across all clients, and these limits are different. If your
>   application requests enough refresh tokens to go over one of the
>   limits, older refresh tokens stop working.

[Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

If your application needs offline access to a Google API, set the API client's access type to offline:

```
$client->setAccessType("offline");
```

Here's an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469225/refreshing-tokens-with-google-api-for-google-calendar-v3/40481457#40481457) an additional sample.