# Google Oauth Asks Permissions Again and Again?

Tags: php, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

Lets say i have following code

```
    $state = 1234;
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('######');
    $client->stClientSecreet('####3');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $client->setState($state);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");       // offline access
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->refreshToken($decoded_refresh);

    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("auto");

    header('Location: '. filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

i have `refresh token` with offline access,when it calls

> header('Location: '. filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

but it again and again show `consent screen` to ask user permission, what mistake i made here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh token with Google API client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241213/how-to-refresh-token-with-google-api-client)

Answer (score 0):

this because your app is unreviewed, to request OAuth Developer Verification go to https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification