# PHP How to upload to Youtube user's channel

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Need to make user's authorizations so server will upload videos to users channels.

Authentication part:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(PROPPATH.'/inc/client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://back url');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$credentialsPath = PROPPATH.'/youtube_auth/user_'.get_current_user_id().'.json';
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
} else {

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
if(!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo '<script>window.location = "'.$authUrl.'";</script>';
} else {
    $authCode = $_GET['code'];
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
}
```

Authentication seems like works and saves some key.
2nd part, trying upload video:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile(PROPPATH.'/inc/client_secret.json');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents(PROPPATH.'/youtube_auth/user_2.json'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$client->setDefer(true);
$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("", $video);
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $insertRequest,
    'video/*',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));
...
```

And i'm getting error:

> A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain":
>   "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>   "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code":
>   401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }
>   What i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

> 401: Invalid Credentials
>
> Invalid authorization header. The access token you're using is either
>   expired or invalid.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization",
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

> Suggested action: Refresh the access token using the long-lived
>   refresh token.

Comment: I just obtained it and trying to use, any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe i need to use different scope to grant access to users channel?

Comment: I think you should check how you are obtaining it make sure the authentication server is in fact refreshing your access token.   The one you are using is expired.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/9241213/1841839

Comment: I have already set offline access on code, any other suggestions?